# Как переменная может быть одновременно и функцией и объектом в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Как реализовать такую запись (как в jQuery для `$`), когда к переменной можно обращаться и как к функции и как к объекту ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На самом деле, функция -- это *полноценный объект* в JavaScript. В этом достаточно просто убедиться:

```
var f = function() {};
console.log(f instanceof Object); // выведет true
```

Как следствие, вы можете добавлять к ней произвольные поля. Например так:

```
// Сначала опрделеяем функцию
var f = function() {
    console.log('test');
};

// А затем добавляем к ней произвольные свойства
f.val = 'another test';

f(); // Выведет "test"
console.log(f.val); // Выведет "another test"
```